# python decorator changing "self" argument : works but looks bad

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

My goal was to make a simple log module with a Log class that I could use in other projects to keep track of things. Especially, I wanted to create a "@tracemethod" decorator to record all method calls (method name and arguments). Here is a very simplified (but functional) version of the class :

```
class Log :

    def __init__(self, path) :
        self.path = path
        # here is a whole path-checking routine.

    def log(self, msg):
        with open(self.path, mode="a+") as log_file :
            log_file.write(msg + "\n")

    def tracemethod(self, f):
        def wrapped(self2, *args, **kwargs) :
            outstring = "{}({},{})".format(f.__name__, str(args), str(kwargs))
            self.log(outstring)
            return f(self2, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
```

And it works, I can call the class in an other module and use it :

```
from log import Log

log1 = Log("/Path/to/existing_log_file.txt")

class Foo() :

    @log1.tracemethod
    def __init__(self, a, b, c) :
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    @log1.tracemethod
    def a_method(self, c, d, e):
        return c+d+e

foo = Foo(4,5, c=5 )
foo.a_method(32, 64, e=9)
```

Which gives in existing_log_file.txt :

```
__init__((4, 5),{'c': 5})
a_method((32, 64),{'e': 9})
```

But as you can see, the "tracemethod" method in the Log class uses a "self2" argument to differentiate the Log instance from the Foo instance using it. I've heard renaming "self" is a big no-no. Whats would be the correct / pythonic way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you actually need to access the wrapped `self`, this is a bit of a dilemma—you have one guideline telling you not to rename either of the `self` parameters, but an even stronger guideline telling you not to shadow one `self` with the other.

There's nothing in PEP 8 to tell you what to do; there's not even an example in the documentation.

---

But there's a reason for that. It's actually pretty rare that you need to access the wrapped `self`. Look at your code: you don't do anything with `self2`:

```
def tracemethod(self, f):
    def wrapped(self2, *args, **kwargs) :
        outstring = "{}({},{})".format(f.__name__, str(args), str(kwargs))
        self.log(outstring)
        return f(self2, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

You do apparently want to skip over it in the output, but you can do that just by slicing `[1:]`. So, just like all of the examples in the docs, leave it in `*args` instead of pulling it out as a separate parameter:

```
def tracemethod(self, f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs) :
        outstring = "{}({},{})".format(f.__name__, str(args[1:]), str(kwargs))
        self.log(outstring)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

So, in your case, problem averted.

---

What about when you can't just get away with this?

In that case, there doesn't seem to be a widely-accepted standard. Really, anything that makes it clear which self is which, and makes it easy to visually distinguish the two, is OK; `self2` doesn't quite cut it there, but AMADANON's `wrappedself` does.

I think the two most common names I've seen are `inner_self` and `wrapped_self` (with or without the underscores), but without doing a more scientific survey, I wouldn't rely on that too much.

I've also seen a tutorial (although I can't remember where) that suggests wrapping everything in another function call just to avoid the issue coming up, but that seems pretty silly to me.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much. Now I have to see if that works with the longer version of my class where I think I actually use self2 a bit more (to get the __class__.__name__ of the calling class for instance). But since there's intrinsically nothing wrong with using an "inner_self" (quite philosophical, really), no problem. I'll see if I really need it.
Thanks a lot, big help for my comprehension.

Comment: @nico7et8: If you can come up with a concrete stripped-down example where you clearly do need the wrapped self, it might be worth asking somewhere better suited to open-ended discussions (like python-list). If you're really lucky, you can get a consensus and suggest adding it to PEP 8; if not, at least you'll get a lot more validation than just a couple guys at SO that your style is Pythonic.

Comment: Wow. Sure, why not. Although as far as I am concerned, being completely new to python, validation from you and amadanon is more than enough. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going down a completely forbidden path. Based on the way you both understood and corrected it, that's all the validation I need. Plus : it works (so far). But yeah : it might be interesting to see how a longer conversation would unfold. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most pythonic way would be to skip the inner "self" altogether, just use *args and **args (args[0] will be "self", if you need it):

```
def tracemethod(self, f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs) :
        outstring = "{}({},{})".format(f.__name__, str(args), str(kwargs))
        self.log(outstring)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

After all, self is one of the parameters. This way your decorator will also work on regular (non-object) functions.

Or, what about replacing "self" with "wrappedself" (or something like that), then you can use "self" instead of "self2":

```
def tracemethod(wrappedself, f):
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs) :
        outstring = "{}({},{})".format(f.__name__, str(args), str(kwargs))
        wrappedself.log(outstring)
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Comment: If you actually _need_ `self`, using `args[0]` is probably not a good idea for readability. But the rest of your answer is great.